# Compilation error using texshade package

Tags: compilation-error

I want to show my DNA sequences from a FASTA file in my LateX document.
The texshade package seems useful for this, but a compilation error emerges when using this package.

Even without using the package, only with the command `\usepackage{texshade}`
I get the error (actually 64 errors).

[image]

I cannot make a MWE, because in a MWE it does works for me somehow!

Any ideas what the problem could be?
Thanks.

Comment: A stray non-ASCII character may have worked its way into your document.  If you recognize any of the error lines as coming directly from your document, you might consider deleting and retyping that line into your document

Comment: Honestly I only started working with LateX and I have no idea were to start looking or where there could be a non-ASCII character in my text... All errors are about "parameter number in definition of \p@r@gr@ph" and everywhere it somehow does not like the # symbol I think.

Comment: You expressed difficulty in making an MWE that breaks.  I suggest making a copy of your document, and start removing extraneous stuff and recompiling.  Eventually, you will either get down to a minimal example that breaks, or you will discover more about what lines of code make it break, if all of a sudden, the removal of a few lines makes it work.

Comment: Yes I could do that. Thanks. It will take some time perhaps because it is a rather large document. I will look into it.

Comment: If possible, use a geometric approach, removing 1/2 the document each iteration.  It may go faster.

Comment: Yes. Good idea. I will have a look tomorrow.